# Do enemies Test attacks at 2d6 or 3d6?

Tags: tiny-dungeon

I'm going to be running my first TinyD6 (Tiny Dungeon 2e) adventure, and I've run into a question that I can't quite figure out:

Are monsters masters of their weapons?  Example: Assassins.  Are Assassins masters of their weapons?  Just proficient?  Bumbling incompetents?

I would think that they would be masters of one weapon, same as adventurers, but adventurers are also intended to be more heroic than your average NPC.

So, do enemies Test at 2d6 or 3d6 when not otherwise specified?

Comment: I know that it's ultimately up to me, but this seems basic enough that there should be a definitive answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The rules don't say, so up to the Gamemaster

As you observe, there is no specific statement on this to be found anywhere in the rules for Tiny Dungeon 2e. So, as per those rules for a minimalist ruleset, this falls back to the "**The Rules Don't Cover That!**" rule on page 21:

> If a situation arises where an Adventurer is asking for a ruling that these rules don't provide an answer to, it is up to the Game Master to provide a ruling. This is known as Game Master fiat. Ultimately the Game Master has final say on how the game is played, and how the rules are enforced. The key is simply to be consistent.

There are good arguements for both using the default test (2d6), or the test for mastery with weapons (3d6):

**2d6**: First, this is the default, normal test, if nothing else is stated. Second, most monsters that have other attacks where the test is called out default to 2d6 tests to execute them, for example the Giant Snake's Constrict melee attack uses 2d6, as does the Kraken's, and the Giant Spiders Web Slinger ranged and Poisonous Bite melee attack. Only a truely terrifying monster like the Red Dragon, an Epic monster even beyond the highest tiered class of Solo, sports a 3d6 Bite attack -- and even its other attacks, the Fire Breath and Tail Swipe, are only 2d6. The same goes for several Epic dinosaurs: most of them have just 2d6 attacks, with a rare 3d6 Bite here or there for Solo or Heroic class opponents.

**3d6**. Every PC gets to pick one weapon they have mastered, which effectively means that every PC attacks with 3d6, and PCs are humans, elves, dwarves etc. The rules (other than for other games) never state that PCs are special or a cut above. Instead they claim on page 24: "*you weren't born as an Adventurer. No, really. You weren't*". It would be logical then that any other human, elf, dwarf or whatever whose occupation and survival was  heavily dependend on being good at using a weapon also would have a mastered weapon.

I would probably give the more mundane enemies of Fodder, Low, or Medium tier only a 2d6, and the deadlier opponents of High, Heroic, or Epic tier that wield weapons a 3d6 attack, because High tier states:

> High threat enemies are just as dangerous as a skilled Adventurer.

If a High tier opponent is "just as dangerous" as an Adventurer, then they should have an attack that is just as dangerous, too (and so should opponents that are even more dangerous). But in the end, it is up to you, as the GM.

Comment: I like your reasoning. This makes sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

First thing I do is check to see if they have any traits that gives them an advantage for them then it would be 2d6.
If not then d6.
If the creature is to be a "boss" final fight or "epic" I would simple bump up the dice to 2d6 and 3d6 to make it a truly freighting encounter.
If it is a weak encounter the d6 for all tasks.

Like your assassin encounter (has the sneaky trait).
Task for him sneaking up on party his advantage. If he succeeds then his attack is also an advantage task. If he fails he is at a disadvantage d6 on attack task.
This will be subjective but as you run the game it will become almost instinctive.

Comment: Welcome to answering on rpg.se. To find out more about site-workings, consider the [tour] and [help]. Do you have a source to back up this ruling? If it is experience based, could you tell us more about how you developed these suggestions?

Comment: Welcome! It's very nice that we're finally getting some answers to these old questions - TY! However, this answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).